# Python - Comma in string causes issue with strip

Tags: python

I have strings as tuples that I'm trying to remove quotation marks from. If there isn't a comma present in the string, then it works. But if there is a comma, then quotation marks still remain:

```
example = [('7-30-17','0x34','"Upload Complete"'),('7-31-17','0x35','"RCM","Interlock error"')]

example = [(x,y,(z.strip('"'))) 
    for x,y,z in example]
```

The result is that quotation marks partially remain in the strings that had commas in them. The second tuple now reads `RCM","Interlock error` as opposed to `RCM, Interlock error`

```
('7-30-17','0x34','Upload Complete')
('7-31-17','0x35','RCM","Interlock error')
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Your naïve approach to stripping quotes is going to be trouble. Be sure to test whatever code you have on something with actual quotes in it.

Comment: It's doing exactly what you told it to do.  strip only removes from the ends of the string, maybe you wanted str.replace.

Comment: `'"RCM","Interlock error"'`  this is ONE string, not two. The string is delimited by `'` only the firstand last  `"` is at the start/end of a string. so it is removed - the other one is _inside_ it - and not touched by `strip()`  .Voting to close, strip is working **exactly** as intended and the comma does nothing to invalidate its mechanics.

Comment: check [python string strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html), `string.strip(s[, chars])`Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters removed.

Comment: Try using `.replace('"', ' ')` instead of using `.strip()`

Comment: @Hevlastka That worked, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for the behaviour of [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), rather than [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Try using `replace('"', '')` instead of `strip('"')`. `strip` only removes characters from the beginning and end of strings, while `replace` will take care of all occurrences.

Your example would be updated to look like this:

```
example = [('7-30-17','0x34','"Upload Complete"'),('7-31-17','0x35','"RCM","Interlock error"')]

example = [(x,y,(z.replace('"', '')))
    for x,y,z in example]
```

`example` ends up with the following value:

```
[('7-30-17', '0x34', 'Upload Complete'), ('7-31-17', '0x35', 'RCM,Interlock error')]
```

Comment: Easy solution! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension to iterate the list items and similarly for the inner tuple items

```
>>> [tuple(s.replace('"','') for s in tup) for tup in example]
[('7-30-17', '0x34', 'Upload Complete'), ('7-31-17', '0x35', 'RCM,Interlock error')]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because `strip` will remove only from ends of string.

Use a `regex` to replace `"`:

```
import re

example = [('7-30-17','0x34','"Upload Complete"'),('7-31-17','0x35','"RCM","Interlock error"')]

example = [(x,y,(re.sub('"','',z))) 
    for x,y,z in example] 

print(example)
# [('7-30-17', '0x34', 'Upload Complete'), ('7-31-17', '0x35', 'RCM,Interlock error')]
```